# Clickable Jobs Locations

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

It would be nice if the locations in the header/sidebar preview of job postings were clickable, with perhaps a link to google maps of the city (or even office) in question.

Often times I come across an interesting posting in my state but in a city I have never heard of. It would be convenient if I could just click the location text and it would bring up a map of where it is, so I can judge how far it would be from my current location.

If the location link would display the exact location of the office that the listing is for (assuming it is not for remote work), that would be even better. I'm not sure if employers currently provide SO with the exact office location, or just the city.

Comment: Employers *can* provide the exact office address, but they don't have to. They have to at least provide the city (except for fully remote jobs)